# Typescript object possibly undefined when looking for objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Typescript faults as an error when you attribute an value to a variable and that value is possibly undefined. That can normally be worked around by inserting `!` after the value you're passing or with a simple `if` statement. The problem is the first is not working for me, and to use the latter would cause me to add an unnecessary amount of extra lines to my code. The scenario is as follow:

I have this interface. I use an array of it as my component state:

```
interface IFormFields {
    name: string; isValid: boolean; content: string; isUnchanged: boolean; tip: string
}

...

const [requiredFields, setRequiredFields] = useState<Array<IFormFields>>([]);
```

And later I want to get `requiredFields` objects to use their values. I want to do it by using JavaScript's `find` method in a one-liner:

```
requiredFields.find(field => field.name === "Nome")
```

This line causes an error, because "field" might be undefined. In this case the K operator causes another error

```
requiredFields.find(field! => field.name === "Nome")
//"Cannot find name 'field'.ts(2304)"
```

And using `if` clauses will cause, like I  said, a huge amount of unnecessary lines of code, because `requiredFields` can have n objects inside it. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a playground. Are you able to? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2UC27gQA2AJgM7IDeAsAFDL3Ihw4QBcypYUoA5gNzJgpAGpxCwYuwBGmTIQhwQAhJnARw7TtxD9BpAKogEAC0U8Ik5DLkKlyMMAAOmrr1oBfWrRUhOyGAQkpOwAglBQcACeADwY2HiBZAB8yAC8yADaALp8XjQBRGQAdAEgxAAUBSRpKVXERUwsaanpAEQAcpgsrQCUfEA

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce this in a typescript/react codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-black-g4tsy?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The problem is that `find` may not find anything, if you're confident it will use `!` at the end of the method call `requiredFields.find(field => field.name === "Nome")!`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova you are correct. I was just updating this section with Nicks's working snippet: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2UC27gQA2AJgM7IDeAsAFDL3Ihw4QBcypYUoA5gNzJgpAGpxCwYuwBGmTIQhwQAhJnARw7TtxD9BpAKogEAC0U8Ik5DLkKlyMMAAOmrr1oBfWrRUhOyGAQkpOwAglBQcACeADwY2HiBZAB8yAC8yADaALp8XjQBRGQAdAEgxAAUBSRpKVXERUwsaanpAEQAcpgsrQCURT6Q4HxAA

Comment: Oh, that doesn't really jibe with the error you posted in the question though?

Comment: Avoid `find` as much as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the `!` operator, you need to do so at the place where you access its properties, i.e.

```
requiredFields.find(field => field!.name === "Nome")
```

However, I would recommend you use the `?` operator instead; that way, if `field` *does* happen to be undefined, you will not get a runtime error:

```
requiredFields.find(field => field?.name === "Nome")
```

In short, `field!.name` just tells the compiler that you know `field` is defined, whereas `field?.name` automatically puts in the `null`/`undefined` check for you (thus avoiding the code clutter).